# How to convert XML without root/parent element to struct?

Tags: xml, go, struct, unmarshalling

API response from remote server (response content-type: text/html):

```
<status>success</status>
<statusmsg>online</statusmsg>
<vmstat>online</vmstat>
<hostname>kvm-vps2</hostname>
<ipaddress>123.456.789.99</ipaddress>
```

I try to parse the API response above to Go struct. None of my approaches below worked:

**Approach #1 code**

```
type result struct {
    Status    string `xml:",chardata"`
    Statusmsg string `xml:",chardata"`
    Vmstat    string `xml:",chardata"`
    Hostname  string `xml:",chardata"`
    Ipaddress string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

**Approach #2 code**

```
type result struct {
    Status    string `xml:"status"`
    Statusmsg string `xml:"statusmsg"`
    Vmstat    string `xml:"vmstat"`
    Hostname  string `xml:"hostname"`
    Ipaddress string `xml:"ipaddress"`
}
```

From approach #1, I only managed to get the `Status` value. Other values were empty. For approach #2, all values were empty.

**Unmarshal code**:

```
// other code
r := result{}
err = xml.Unmarshal(body, &r)
// other code
```

What should be fixed here so that I can access all the API response values?

Comment: Wrap the payload into an xml element. https://play.golang.com/p/OBEbjPLv5lm

Comment: Your xml is not well formed because it has an array at the root instead of one noded at the root.  You can use XmlReader with XmlReaderSettings set as follows :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
             settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
             XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);  If you have a string then use StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml string)  and then use the string reader in the Create instead of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That response is not a valid XML document, so you can't decode it as-is in one step or without modification / "decoration".

Below solutions use `body` as the unread response body stream: [`Response.Body`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Body).

### 1. Decoding as a series of XML documents

However, it can be looked at as a *series* of XML documents, and so you may use [`xml.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) to decode them one-by-one.

For example:

```
var res result
dec := xml.NewDecoder(body)

var err error
decField := func(v interface{}) {
    if err == nil {
        err = dec.Decode(v)
    }
}
decField(&res.Status)
decField(&res.Statusmsg)
decField(&res.Vmstat)
decField(&res.Hostname)
decField(&res.Ipaddress)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/m8VzvR1h2rX)):

```
{Status:success Statusmsg:online Vmstat:online Hostname:kvm-vps2 Ipaddress:123.456.789.99}
```

Yes, it's inconvenient to decode field-by-field.

### 2. Reading body and wrapping with a root tag

Another option is to wrap it with a tag to make it a valid XML document:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf.WriteString("<root>")
if _, err := io.Copy(buf, body); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
buf.WriteString("</root>")

var res result
if err := xml.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &res); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
```

This outputs the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZbGzx-2gQEC).

Yes, the above solution must read the body first into memory.

### 3. Wrapping the body stream without reading it into memory

We can avoid having to read and keep the body in memory though. We may construct a reader that upon reading first provides the opening wrapper tag, then the "original" body, and last the closing tag. For this, we may use [`io.MultiReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader):

```
r := io.MultiReader(
    strings.NewReader("<root>"),
    body,
    strings.NewReader("</root>"),
)

var res result
if err := xml.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&res); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
```

This again outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ap_jZh4TQKS).

Comment: I tried all proposals above. Both gave me `cannot use body (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to io.Copy:
 []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)` error. My `body` came from `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`. Any idea?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin Because the `body` in my answer is the original, unread body stream: `Response.Body`. I mentioned this at the top of my answer. Your `body` is the already read data as a byte slice.

Comment: Thanks. I tried number 3 using `resp.Body` and it worked.